# Pandas Dataframe used for Train_Test_Split

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following dataset which I want to analyze using the K-Nearest-Neighbor using pandas and sklearn:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval

First I load the dataset in a dataframe, with headers (`A1` to `A16`) for each column:

```
df =  pd.read_csv('crx.csv').dropna().reset_index(drop = True)
```

My question is , how do I use the `train_test_split` function to:

a) Split the data in test and train **and**

b) Also flag the columns `A1` to `A15` as features and `A16` as label?

I would like to have something like the below code, which of course doesn't work as I would like:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[0:16], df['A16'], random_state=0)
```

where `X_train` will have 75% of data from column `A1` to `A15`, `X_test` the rest 25%, `y_train` the same 75% of data but only the column `A16` (target) and `y_test` the rest 25%.

My intention is later to use `KNeighborsClassifier.fit` with the training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.iloc[:,0:16]` instead (or `df[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', ...]]`, but that is more cumbersome in your case):

```
train_test_tuple = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,0:16], df['A16'], random_state=0)
```

See the [documentation for iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).